# Print inner elements of node

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I've got an XML-File like this one

```
<users>
  <user>
    <name>X</name>
    <description>
      This is a <it>description</it> of the <a href="www.google.com">user</a>.
    </description>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>Y</name>
    <description>
      This is a <it>description</it> of another user.
    </description>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>Z</name>
    <description>
      This is a description of the <a href="www.google.com">third</a> user.
    </description>
  </user>
</users>
```

And I have to create an XSL-File to convert it into an HTML that looks like this:

```
<h1>Users</h1>
<h2>X</h2>
<p>This is a <it>description</it> of the <a href="www.google.com">user</a>.</p>
<h2>Y</h2>
<p>This is a <it>description</it> of another user.</p>
<h2>Z</h2>
<p>This is a description of the <a href="www.google.com">third</a> user.</p>
```

So basically I need to get the raw data of the `<description>` tag and print it into a paragraph. But I have no idea how to do that. Any ideas?

My XSL-Code so far:

```
<xsl:for-each select="users/user">
  <h2><xsl:value-of select="name" /></h2>
  <p><xsl:value-of select="description"/></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: got it. i substituted `<xsl:value-of select="description" />` with `<xsl:copy-of select="description" />` and XSLT copied everything from the description-tag to the <p>-Tag.
Completly forgot about that...

Comment: I suppose your xsl code also generates < html > tags somewhere matching / etc.pp. but excellent that you solved your problem!